# android multipart send to server images by ArrayList<image>

Tags: android, image, multipart

I want to send multiple images to server by byte[]. But only one image arrives to server.

This is my codes, please let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

    String result = null;
    URL httpurl;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream dos;

    try {

        httpurl = new URL(url[0]);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) httpurl.openConnection();
        conn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+ HTTP_FILE_BOUNDARY);

        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes("--" + HTTP_FILE_BOUNDARY + "\r\n");

        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\""  + "\r\n\r\n"); 
        dos.writeBytes(params.key);
        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
        dos.writeBytes("--" + HTTP_FILE_BOUNDARY + "\r\n");

        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"memo\""  + "\r\n\r\n"); 
        dos.write(params.memo.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
        dos.writeBytes("--" + HTTP_FILE_BOUNDARY + "\r\n");

        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"list_menu\""  + "\r\n\r\n"); 
        dos.write(params.list_menu.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
        dos.writeBytes("--" + HTTP_FILE_BOUNDARY + "\r\n");

        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"lat\""  + "\r\n\r\n"); 
        dos.write(params.lat.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
        dos.writeBytes("--" + HTTP_FILE_BOUNDARY + "\r\n");

        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"lon\""  + "\r\n\r\n"); 
        dos.write(params.lon.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
        dos.writeBytes("--" + HTTP_FILE_BOUNDARY + "\r\n");

        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"update\""  + "\r\n\r\n"); 
        dos.writeBytes(params.update);
        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
        dos.writeBytes("--" + HTTP_FILE_BOUNDARY + "\r\n");

        for(int i=0; i<params.photolist.size(); i++){
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\""+ i +;" filename=\"" + params.fileName + "\"" + "\r\n");
            dos.writeBytes("\"" + "\r\n");
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + "\r\n\r\n");
            if ( params.photolist.get(i) != null ) {
                dos.write(params.photolist.get(i));
            }
            dos.writeBytes("\r\n");

            dos.writeBytes("--" + HTTP_FILE_BOUNDARY+ "--" + "\r\n"); 
        }

        dos.flush();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        String line = null;
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    if(sb != null){
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i think you have to call web service every time for every image.because multipart fetch one image uri at a time ,and after upload one image it finish

Comment: Use a library and don't mess up your codes!

Comment: you can use volley. that works fine for multiple images. just need to add custom a class for uploading multiple image as multipart entry. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448003/upload-multiple-images-using-volley-library-in-android)